# Equivalent to "stay tuned", but not for TV or radio?

Tags: popular-refrains

I need to advertise that new hours will be announced in the future, in a simple way that sounds professional.

"Stay tuned" would be perfect, except the fact that this is for print, not for TV or radio.

**Is there a close equivalent in the English language to "stay tuned"?**

Comment: Traditional for print is "Watch this space", but there's no reason "Stay tuned" wouldn't work. People have heard it so often it's become commonplace, even in conversation. [No citations, so only a comment]

Comment: "Stay tuned" is certainly enough of a set phrase to work.  I've seen/heard it used several times in similar situations.

Comment: Make a print ad with the words in a speech balloon coming from a picture of a radio if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Stay tuned" would be perfectly acceptable even for print. For sure, it originated with media needing tuning, but has come to be a more general term meaning "keep paying attention for new developments."

See the description in [Wiktionary:](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stay_tuned)

> 1. (idiomatic) To remain as a listener or viewer of the particular radio station or television channel to which one is currently paying attention.
> 2. (idiomatic, by extension, often as imperative) To wait or remain alert (for new developments or for further information).

Comment: Totally. After all we can *consider* what those new hours might be without looking at the stars, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

**Stand by**

> Stand by: (*Verb*) To wait in expectation of some event; to make ready. [Definitions](http://www.definitions.net/)

Answer (score 0):

**Keep focused on this space.**

> focus (v intr.) - concentrate attention or energy [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/focused)

- "When you do your homework, you better keep focused!"
- "Keep your mind focused on your goal."